# How do I install ngc as a project specific cli tool?

Tags: angular, tooling

I am trying to install the angular compiler (ngc) as a project specific dependency for my nativescript plugin. But there is no info on how to install it.

I want to be able to run:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ngc
```

Answer (score 0):

The ngc command line tool for the compiler can be installed using

```
npm add @angular/compiler-cli
```

Comment: Do you know how to run this node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json? , I"m facing node_modules is not recognized command,